# put array value of one file php into an other array of an other file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know there are a lot of similar question but I didn't find how to do that.  I have one array in test.php

```
[
{
    "_id": "89",
    "name": "rfg",
    "author": "toto",
    "description": "",
    "status": "draft",
    "skills": [],
    "creationDate": "2008-07-17T07:49:05.000Z",
    "modificationDate": "2010-09-17T07:49:05.179Z"
}, ...
```

And I want to put all these values in an array "modules" which is in final.php

```
[
{
    "_id": "89446259",
    "name": "something",
    "description": "coco",
    "programTemplate": "895",
    "author": "tutu",
    "tutors": [
        "titi"
    ],
    "startDate": "2018-10-05T13:49:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2019-10-05T13:49:00.000Z",
    "skills": [],
    "modules": [
        {
            "_id": "89",
            "type": "course"
        },
        {
            "_id": "102",
            "type": "course"
        },
        {
            "type": "something",
            "name": "choose"
        }
    ]
}, ...
```

The result as I want is if Id is the same in final.php and in test.php so I put the value.
For example, if the value '_id' in final.php is the same of the value '_id' of test.php so 'name', 'author', 'description', etc. will come in final.php.

Result I want:

```
[
{
    "_id": "89446259",
    "name": "something",
    "description": "coco",
    "programTemplate": "895",
    "author": "tutu",
    "tutors": [
        "titi"
    ],
    "startDate": "2018-10-05T13:49:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2019-10-05T13:49:00.000Z",
    "skills": [],
    "modules": [
        {
            "_id": "89",
            "type": "course",
            "name": "rfg",
            "author": "toto",
            "description": "",
            "status": "draft",
            "skills": [],
            "creationDate": "2008-07-17T07:49:05.000Z",
            "modificationDate": "2010-09-17T07:49:05.179Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "102",
            "type": "course"
        },
        {
            "type": "something",
            "name": "choose"
        }
    ]
}, ...
```

My PHP code in final.php

```
require_once('courses.php');

// initialisation
$results = curl_init( );

// configuration
//session
curl_setopt( $results, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ex.myapi.com/call_api" );
curl_setopt( $results, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// récupération du fichier
$result = curl_exec( $results );
$toto=json_decode($result);

//$objArray = json_decode($rows);

$newarray = array();
foreach ($toto as &$t){

    $modules=$t->modules;
    foreach ($modules as $m){
        $coco='787';    
            
         
        $m->testId= $val;
        if ($m->testId == $m->_id){
            $m->names = $name;
        $m->description = $desc;
        $m->author = $author;
        $m->status = $status;
        $m->creaDate = $creaDate;
        $m->modifDate = $modifDate; 
        
        
        // $m->toto = $coco;
        $newarray[] = $m;
    }

}
print_r($toto);
echo json_encode($toto);
    
curl_close( $results );
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please explain better what happened if _id is the same.

Comment: I edit my question, hope it's clear enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test.php:

```
$test1 = $decoded_json_object; // YOUR **DECODED** JSON OBJECT FROM test.php
```

final.php:

```
require_once( 'test.php' );

$test2 = $decoded_json_object_2 // YOUR **DECODED** JSON OBJECT FROM final.php

foreach( $test1 as &$course )  {
  foreach( $test2 as &$program )  {
    foreach( $program->modules as &$module ) {
      if( $module->_id == $course->_id ) {
        $module = (object) array_merge( (array) $module, (array) $course);
      }
    }
  }
}

$test2 = json_encode( $test2 );
```

Comment: I don't know why but it don't work. I forgot to tell that i recover these to array from 2 api and I can't put them in a file

Comment: These two arrays are json objects. Can you show your API-Call? Any errors?

Comment: I don't have error, I call them with cURL and when I print the "new json", I just have "this page don't work

Comment: Please add your full code to your question. You can delete api-keys and so on.

Comment: Have you renamed the vars $test1 and $test2 everywhere correctly?

Comment: Yes I did a test in an other file with your code and I change all the value

Comment: It can only be wrong duplicates of json_decode or wrong var names. In your final.php you echo $toto but dont save it. Is it the object you posted in your question?

Comment: I don't save it, I never save a json_decode, we need  to ? And yes toto is the object

Comment: I have edited the answer. You have to replace $test1 with your decoded json object from test.php and replace $test2 with your decoded json object from final.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207831/discussion-between-anono-and-robingillitzer).